# onTouch is triggered again on back button pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have this code in the onCreate method:

```
    ImageView iv01 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hexagon01);        
    iv01.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ChoiceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

When I touch the image the new activity loads correctly. I can go back pressing back button. But when I press the back button again, to close the app, it launches again the onTouch event, loading again the activity. How can I avoid it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I touch the image the new activity loads correctly. I can go back pressing back button. But when I press the back button again, to close the app, it launches again the onTouch event, loading again the activity.

Honestly, the back button doesn't launch new copies of your Activity. Your OnTouchListener launches a new copy of the Activity for each `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, and `ACTION_UP` MotionEvent. But you only notice the numerous Activities when you try to close the active Activity...

Simply ensure that you only launch the new Activity on *one* MotionEvent:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ChoiceActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or you could use an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) here instead.

Answer (score 1):

OnTouchListener gets triggered for several reasons (you need to check the MotionEvent parameter in order to find the exact reason). It seems you should just use an OnClickListener and achieve the same thing in an easier way.